# not able to save data in django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am getting error Cannot assign "'1'": "dropdown.drp1" must be a "basedrop" instance. I am sharing my code. Kindly help. I got some solutions on stack but I did not understand how to implement that in my case. [Django error. Cannot assign must be an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839867/django-error-cannot-assign-must-be-an-instance)

models.py

```
class basedrop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class subdrop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,null=False)
    bsdrop = models.ForeignKey(basedrop,null=False,blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class lastdrop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,null=False)
    sbdrop = models.ForeignKey(subdrop,null=False,blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class dropdown(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    drp1 = models.ForeignKey(basedrop,max_length=50,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    drp2 = models.ForeignKey(subdrop,max_length=50,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    drp3 = models.ForeignKey(lastdrop,max_length=50,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def create_drop(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = dropdownForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = dropdown(name=request.POST.get('name'),drp1_Id=int(request.POST.get('drp1')),
                drp2_Id=int(request.POST.get('drp2')),drp3_Id=int(request.POST.get('drp3')))
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('<p>this is working</p>')
    form = dropdownForm()
    return render(request,'drop.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class dropdownForm(forms.ModelForm):

drp1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=((bs.get('id'),bs.get('name')) for bs in basedrop.objects.all().values('id','name')))
class Meta:
    model = dropdown
    fields = '__all__'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['drp2'].queryset = subdrop.objects.none()
    self.fields['drp3'].queryset = lastdrop.objects.none()

    if 'drp1' in self.data:
        try:
            country_id = int(self.data.get('drp1'))
            self.fields['drp2'].queryset = subdrop.objects.filter(id=country_id).order_by('name')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass
    elif 'drp2' in self.data:
        try:
            country_id = int(self.data.get('drp2'))
            self.fields['drp3'].queryset = lastdrop.objects.filter(id=country_id).order_by('name')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass
    elif self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['drp2'].queryset = self.instance.drp1.city_set.order_by('name')
        self.fields['drp3'].queryset = self.instance.drp2.city_set.order_by('name')
```

Comment: Can you mark the line where the error comes from? Is the full code accessible (eg. github)?

Comment: @Frank getting error at ''if form.is_valid()''

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could cause failures but you're passing the POSTed argument 'drp1' as integer for drp1_Id, drp2_Id and drp3_Id.

---

You'd have it much easier if you choose a more intuitive coding style.

For example this line:

```py
form = dropdown(name=request.POST.get('name'), drp1_Id=int(request.POST.get('drp1')), drp2_Id=int(request.POST.get('drp1')), drp3_Id=int(request.POST.get('drp1')))
```

If you get the objects and pass them to the dropdown you gain readability specially if there is an error:

```py
drp1_pk = request.POST.get('drp1')
drp1 = basedrop.objects.get(pk=drp1_pk)
drp2 = subdrop.objects.get(pk=drp1_pk)
drp3 = lastdrop.objects.get(pk=drp1_pk)
form = dropdown(name=request.POST.get('name'), drp1=drp1, drp2=drp2, drp3=drp3)
```

But again:
It looks strange to pass the same primary key to three different models.

Comment: Sorry, for my mistake in views.py. Actually, I am passing 3 different primary keys to each model. I have updated my views.py. Let me try, the solution you gave me and get back to you.

Comment: first thing, it should be form = dropdown(name=request.POST.get('name'), drp1=drp1, drp2=drp2, drp3=drp3), right? second thing is I am getting error on the same line __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'