# How to save a Foreign Key in Django without instance, but a hard coded value

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have these 2 models:

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    order_id = models.ForeignKey('orders.Order', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ean = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The orders are already populated in the database, now I just want to link the shipments to the related order. But I have a list of hardcoded JSON to populate my shipment model.

```
{
"shipmentId": 541757635,
"orderId": 23598235,
}
```

So the orderId in that JSON represents the primary key of a Order model that is **already** present in the database. How can I loop over this to connect the shipment model with the correct order model based on the order_id?

Maybe a loop like this:

```
for shipment in shipments:
    shipment = Shipment.objects.create(id=shipment.shipmentId, order_id=shipment.orderId
```

But is this possible because there is no instance, just a hard coded value in the JSON?

**UPDATE:**
So when I try to use this loop I get this error:

```
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "2647598550": "Shipment.order_id" must be a "Order" instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example loop should do it. You can specify the ID to be anything you want, as long as you do it before calling `.save()`. Building the instance with `.create(id=foo)` should do exactly that.

To set a foreign key field, you can first `get` the related instance using the id with `Order.objects.get(id=order_id)`.

Example code:

```
for shipment in shipments:
    order = Order.objects.get(id=shipment.orderId)
    shipment = Shipment.objects.create(id=shipment.shipmentId, 
                                       order_id=order)
```

Related: [Django error. Cannot assign must be an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839867/django-error-cannot-assign-must-be-an-instance)

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#explicitly-specifying-auto-primary-key-values

Comment: If I do this I get this error: `ValueError: Cannot assign "2647598550": "Shipment.order_id" must be a "Order" instance.`

Comment: This will run a query to find the order and load the entire instance.