# ValueError at /signup/ Cannot assign "<User: prosenjit>": "Referral.parent" must be a "Referral" instance

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys, instance

After reading a lot of answers similar to this problem I got a specific error in every single case.
In the following, I have attached my mandatory code.

## Models.py

```
import uuid
import enum
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone, translation
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation

from django_numerators.models import NumeratorMixin
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey, TreeManager

_ = translation.gettext_lazy
from .utils import generate_ref_code

class Referral(NumeratorMixin, MPTTModel, models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Referral')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Referral')
        unique_together = ('parent', 'account')

    limit = 3

    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='downlines',
        verbose_name=_('Up Line'))
    account = models.OneToOneField(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_('account'))
    balance = models.DecimalField(
        default=0,
        max_digits=15,
        decimal_places=2,
        editable=False,
        verbose_name=_("Balance"))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            self.account.username
            if self.account.get_full_name() in ['', None]
            else self.account.get_full_name()
        )

    def update_balance(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance
        self.save()

    def get_referral_limit(self):
        return getattr(settings, 'REFERRAL_DOWNLINE_LIMIT', None) or self.limit

    def get_uplines(self):
        return self.get_ancestors(include_self=False, ascending=True)[:self.get_referral_limit()]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.code == "":
            code = generate_ref_code()
            self.code = code
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Everything is working well and 100% worked if I add foreignkey instead of TreeForeignKey in the parent field**

```
parent = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='ref_by')
```

**Instead Of**

```
parent = TreeForeignKey(
            'self', null=True, blank=True,
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
            related_name='downlines',
            verbose_name=_('Up Line'))
```

But I need TreeForeignKey because of my **multilevel referral system**.

## utils.py

```
import uuid
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from uuid import UUID
import random


def generate_ref_code():
    code = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-", "")[:12]

    return code
```

## signals.py

```
from .models import Referral
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def post_save_create_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Referral.objects.create(account=instance)
```

## views.py

```
@csrf_protect
def signup_view(request):
    profile_id = request.session.get('ref_profile')
    print('profile_id', profile_id)
    form = SignupForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        if profile_id is not None:
            recommended_by_profile = Referral.objects.get(id=profile_id)
            print("recommended_by_profile", recommended_by_profile)

            instance = form.save()
            print("instance saved", instance)
            registered_user = User.objects.get(id=instance.id)
            print("registered_user", registered_user)
            registered_profile = Referral.objects.get(account=registered_user)
            print("registered_profile", registered_profile)
            registered_profile.parent = recommended_by_profile.account
            print("registered_profile.parent", registered_profile.parent)
            # print("registered_profile.user", registered_profile.user)
            print("registered_profile.account", registered_profile.account)
            print("recommended_by_profile.parent", recommended_by_profile.parent)
            # print("recommended_by_profile.user", recommended_by_profile.user)
            print("recommended_by_profile.account", recommended_by_profile.account)
            registered_profile.save()
            print("registered_profile it's saved", registered_profile)
        else:
            print("Referral not working")
            form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('main_view')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```

I have also attached the image of the error where you can see the specific one. Here is the main issues with a data type that is not passing on the "parent" field when using "TreeForeignKey".

[image]

Any kind of help or suggestion would be appreciated related the question.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37839867/494134

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for your answer. But It's not working for me as well the problem was specific as I said and I read the all of answers related to these questions.