# Cannot assign "'12'": "Receive.registerleson" must be a "Registerleson" instance

Tags: django

error :

> ValueError at /operation/member/RecivVoucher/339/
> Cannot assign "'3'": "Receive.registerleson" must be a "Registerleson" instance.

`model :`

```
class Receive(models.Model):
student = models.ForeignKey("user.Profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='زبان آموز',
                            related_name='receives')
factor = models.ForeignKey("product.Factor", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='فاکتور', null=True, blank=True)
registerleson = models.ForeignKey("member.Registerleson", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='ثبت نام', null=True, blank=True)
term = models.ForeignKey("term.Term", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='سال', null=True, blank=True)
personnel = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='ثبات', null=True, blank=True)
price = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='مبلغ دریافتی')
code_peygiri = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='کد پیگیری', unique=True)
date_pardakht = models.DateField(verbose_name='تاریخ پرداخت', null=True, blank=True)
bank = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='بانک', null=True, blank=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='توضیحات', blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
babat = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Babat, verbose_name='بابت', null=True, blank=True)
```

> view :

```
def RecivVoucher(request, id):
member = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=id)
term = get_object_or_404(Term, termjari=1)
form = ReceiveForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ReceiveForm(request.POST)
    price = request.POST['price'].replace(",", "")
    if form.is_valid():
        fs = form.save(commit=False)
        fs.student = member
        fs.term = term
        fs.price = price
        fs.personnel = request.user.id
        fs.babat = request.POST['babat']
        fs.registerleson = request.POST['hazine']
        if request.POST['babat'] == 1:
            fs.registerleson = request.POST['hazine']
        if request.POST['babat'] == 2:
            fs.factor = request.POST['hazine']
        fs.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,
                             'ثبت با موفقیت انجام شد')
        redirect('RecivVoucher', id)
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING,
                             'خطا در ثبت اطلاعات')
        redirect('RecivVoucher', id)

context = {
    'member': member,
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'member/RecivVoucher.html', context)
```

error :

> ValueError at /operation/member/RecivVoucher/339/
> Cannot assign "'3'": "Receive.registerleson" must be a "Registerleson" instance.

Comment: use `fs.registerleson_id` and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840037/16250404)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are creating a field of type foreign key, Django creates `field_id` automatically. So you can use `registerleson_id` in your view as

```
...
fs.registerleson_id = request.POST['hazine']
...
fs.save()
...
```

[Database representation of foreign key in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)